# Two Facebook login inside 1 app, both redirects me to same page (Both login forcefully takes me to home activity every time after successful login)

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

i have implemented Facebook Login in my app in `Login_v.java` class.
And if successfully logged in, than i am taking user to `Home_v.java` class.

Also i have provided Facebook Login on `AddFbFriends.java` class.
The problem is, when i login from AddFbFriends class, than also the user is redirected to `Home.java` class.
What can be the problem or possibilities for this...?

Any help will be appreciated.

Note: I am using FacebookSDK for android

`Login_v.java`

In Facebook's UpdateUI method, i am checking on server if the user exists.
By using `AsyncTask Method`. If exists, than i am taking user on `Home_v.java` class, else i am Registering the user and than Redirecting to `Home_v.java` class by using `CheckOnServer AsyncTask Code`.

```
private void updateUI() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (user != null) {
            Log.e("Name", user.getName());
            if (user.getProperty("email") != null) {
                Log.e("E-Mail", user.getProperty("email").toString());
            }               
            Log.e("id", user.getId());

            sp = getSharedPreferences("FacebookDetails", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sp.edit();
            ed.putString("fbId", user.getId());
            ed.putString("fbName", user.getName());
            if (user.getProperty("email") != null) {
                ed.putString("fbEmail", user.getProperty("email").toString());
            }               
            ed.commit();                
            new CheckOnServer().execute(user.getProperty("email").toString(),"facebook",user.getName());
        }
    }
```

`AddFbFriends.java` I am just saving the Data Fetched from facebook in Preferences. But still its taking me to `Home_v.java` class

```
private void updateUI() {
        Log.e("Update", "UI");
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (user != null) {
            Log.e("Name", user.getName());
            if (user.getProperty("email") != null) {
                Log.e("E-Mail", user.getProperty("email").toString());
            }               
            Log.e("id", user.getId());

            sp = getSharedPreferences("FacebookDetailsInside", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sp.edit();
            ed.putString("fbId", user.getId());
            ed.putString("fbName", user.getName());
            if (user.getProperty("email") != null) {
                ed.putString("fbEmail", user.getProperty("email").toString());
            }               
            ed.commit();                
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you setting a callback with login anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have [registered a callback](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.2#callback_handling) somewhere in your code. You are probably registering a callback somewhere within which you are navigating to your Home_v.java. Regardless of whether you login from `Login_v.java` or `AddFbFriends.java` if there is a callback set, it is fired on login which is probably what is causing the navigation.

Comment: I thought the same when this scenario happened. I removed the Intent from CallBack but still takes me to `Home_v.java`